# AWS S3 list all data format in a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way how I can list all data format stored in S3 bucket (>13TB) and also get aggregated value how many objects have those format?

Comment: Yes, use S3 Inventory. Once complete, you can post-process its outcome to get what you want.

Comment: S3 inventory does not identify the format of the objects (CSV, parquet..) , which I think is what the question was asking?